# Matching character * in Regex (Java)

Tags: java, regex

Want to match the character * in

> String s ="foobar*";

I want to get the exact character * with one regex character and I don't want to use exclude everything else like

> s.matches("[^\w]");

Comment: Why `with one regex character`, presumably this means you don't want to simply escape it `\\*`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about following:

```
s.matches("\\*");
```

Answer (score 6):

to match the asterisk you need this regex:

```
Pattern asteriskPattern = Pattern.compile("\\*");
```

But I don't see a good use of that pattern. If all you want to do is check if your string contains it, use

```
boolean stringContainsAsterisk = string.contains("*");
```

or find it's index

```
int indexOfAsterisk = string.indexOf("*");
```

now the value is -1 if it does not contain the asterisk, or the value of it's index in the string.

Comment: Damn, you were 6 seconds faster than me :)